# How to open an SSH session in an SSH session with Net::SSH?

Tags: ruby, ssh, tunnel

I need to SSH to the `database` server, which is located in a private subnetwork, through the public `nat` server. Only `nat` has an RSA key that allows to connect to `database`. How would I do that using `Net::SSH`?

I've tried the following:

```
def ssh
  Net::SSH.start(DB_SERVER_IP, DB_SERVER_USERNAME, proxy: proxy)
end

def proxy
  Net::SSH::Proxy::Command.new("ssh -l #{NAT_USER} -e none #{NAT_IP} exec nc %h %p 2>/dev/null")        
end
```

This approach does make the private `database` server visible to `localhost`, but `localhost` doesn't have an RSA key to connect to it, and the connection fails with

```
Permission denied (publickey).
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A workaround:

```
def ssh
  Net::SSH.start(DB_SERVER_IP, DB_SERVER_USERNAME, proxy: proxy, key_data: [pem])
end

def proxy
  Net::SSH::Proxy::Command.new("ssh -l #{NAT_USER} -e none #{NAT_IP} exec nc %h %p 2>/dev/null")        
end

def pem
  Net::SSH.start(NAT_IP, NAT_USER).exec!('cat ~/.ssh/the.pem')
end
```